# AVFoundation tap to focus feedback rectangle

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avfoundation

I am developing an iphone application where I directly use AVFoundation to capture videos via the camera.

I've implemented a feature to enable the `tap to focus` function for a user.

```
- (void) focus:(CGPoint) aPoint;
{
#if HAS_AVFF
    Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
    if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {        
        AVCaptureDevice *device = [captureDeviceClass defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported] &&
           [device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus]) {
            CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            double screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
            double screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
            double focus_x = aPoint.x/screenWidth;
            double focus_y = aPoint.y/screenHeight;
            if([device lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
                [device setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(focus_x,focus_y)];
                [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
                if ([device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose]){
                    [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose];
                }
                [device unlockForConfiguration];
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

So far so good, but I am missing the feedback rectangle like in the photos app. Is there any way to tell the AVFoundation Framework to show this feedback rectangle or do I have to implement this feature myself?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but, you should be using `if (CaptureDeviceClass != Nil)`

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I haven't really cared and known about the differences by now so I looked it up. Due to the fact that I am referencing a class you're absolutely right.

Comment: @Alexander, I am facing in same problem as yours. Did you solve this problem?

Comment: unfortunately I haven't solved this issue yet. I think there is only one way - custom implementation. I've found no build in solution

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here's what I did:
This is the class that creates the square that is shown when the user taps on the camera overlay.

```
CameraFocusSquare.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CameraFocusSquare : UIView
@end


CameraFocusSquare.m

#import "CameraFocusSquare.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

const float squareLength = 80.0f;
@implementation FBKCameraFocusSquare

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
        [self.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

        CABasicAnimation* selectionAnimation = [CABasicAnimation
                                                animationWithKeyPath:@"borderColor"];
        selectionAnimation.toValue = (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        selectionAnimation.repeatCount = 8;
        [self.layer addAnimation:selectionAnimation
                          forKey:@"selectionAnimation"];

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

And in the view where you receive your taps, do the following:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    [self focus:touchPoint];

    if (camFocus)
    {
        [camFocus removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[FBKVideoRecorderView class]])
    {
        camFocus = [[CameraFocusSquare alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(touchPoint.x-40, touchPoint.y-40, 80, 80)];
        [camFocus setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self addSubview:camFocus];
        [camFocus setNeedsDisplay];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
        [camFocus setAlpha:0.0];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

- (void) focus:(CGPoint) aPoint;
{
    Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
    if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {
        AVCaptureDevice *device = [captureDeviceClass defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported] &&
           [device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus]) {
            CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            double screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
            double screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
            double focus_x = aPoint.x/screenWidth;
            double focus_y = aPoint.y/screenHeight;
            if([device lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
                [device setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(focus_x,focus_y)];
                [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
                if ([device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose]){
                    [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose];
                }
                [device unlockForConfiguration];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @iqueqiorio camFocus is a variable of type CameraFocusSquare, the custom class (first snippet of code).

Comment: Okay so how do I declare that, I am trying `CameraFocusSquare *camFocus = [[CameraFocusSquare alloc] init];` but this is giving me an error?

Comment: What does it say? Imported CameraFocusSquare.h ?

Answer (score 13):

Adding to Anil's brilliant answer: Instead of doing the calculations yourself, you should have a look at *AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer*'s *captureDevicePointOfInterestForPoint:*. It will give you a much more consistent focus point (available from iOS 6 and forward).

```
- (void) focus:(CGPoint) aPoint;
{
    Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
    if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {
        AVCaptureDevice *device = [captureDeviceClass defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported] &&
           [device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus]) {

            CGPoint focusPoint = [self.captureVideoPreviewLayer captureDevicePointOfInterestForPoint:aPoint];
            if([device lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
                [device setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(focusPoint.x,focusPoint.y)];
                [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
                if ([device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose]){
                    [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose];
                }
                [device unlockForConfiguration];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The documentation is available here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer/captureDevicePointOfInterestForPoint:

Comment: I think you can simply say [device setFocusPointOfInterest: focusPoint]

Answer (score 10):

**Swift implementation:**

CameraFocusSquare view:

```
    class CameraFocusSquare: UIView,CAAnimationDelegate {

    internal let kSelectionAnimation:String = "selectionAnimation"

    fileprivate var _selectionBlink: CABasicAnimation?

    convenience init(touchPoint: CGPoint) {
        self.init()
        self.updatePoint(touchPoint)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        initBlink()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    fileprivate func initBlink() {
        // create the blink animation
        self._selectionBlink = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
        self._selectionBlink!.toValue = (UIColor.white.cgColor as AnyObject)
        self._selectionBlink!.repeatCount = 3
        // number of blinks
        self._selectionBlink!.duration = 0.4
        // this is duration per blink
        self._selectionBlink!.delegate = self
    }



    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    /**
     Updates the location of the view based on the incoming touchPoint.
     */

    func updatePoint(_ touchPoint: CGPoint) {
        let squareWidth: CGFloat = 100
        let frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: touchPoint.x - squareWidth / 2, y: touchPoint.y - squareWidth / 2, width: squareWidth, height: squareWidth)
        self.frame = frame
    }
    /**
     This unhides the view and initiates the animation by adding it to the layer.
     */

    func animateFocusingAction() {

        if let blink = _selectionBlink {
            // make the view visible
            self.alpha = 1.0
            self.isHidden = false
            // initiate the animation
            self.layer.add(blink, forKey: kSelectionAnimation)
        }

    }
    /**
     Hides the view after the animation stops. Since the animation is automatically removed, we don't need to do anything else here.
     */

    public func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool){
        if flag{
            // hide the view
            self.alpha = 0.0
            self.isHidden = true
        }
    }

}
```

Gesture action:

```
 open func tapToFocus(_ gesture : UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began) {

        let touchPoint:CGPoint = gesture.location(in: self.previewView)

        if let fsquare = self.focusSquare {
            fsquare.updatePoint(touchPoint)
        }else{
            self.focusSquare = CameraFocusSquare(touchPoint: touchPoint)
            self.previewView.addSubview(self.focusSquare!)
            self.focusSquare?.setNeedsDisplay()
        }

        self.focusSquare?.animateFocusingAction()

        let convertedPoint:CGPoint = self.previewLayer!.captureDevicePointOfInterest(for: touchPoint)

        let currentDevice:AVCaptureDevice = self.videoDeviceInput!.device

        if currentDevice.isFocusPointOfInterestSupported && currentDevice.isFocusModeSupported(AVCaptureFocusMode.autoFocus){

            do {

                try currentDevice.lockForConfiguration()
                currentDevice.focusPointOfInterest = convertedPoint
                currentDevice.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.autoFocus

                if currentDevice.isExposureModeSupported(AVCaptureExposureMode.continuousAutoExposure){
                    currentDevice.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.continuousAutoExposure
                }
                currentDevice.isSubjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled = true
                currentDevice.unlockForConfiguration()

            } catch {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

@Anil's answer is a great start, but it didn't work for me. I wanted to be able to have the user continue to be able to select a focus point, instead of only once (which is what his solution does). Thanks to @Anil for pointing me in the right direction.

There are some differences with my solution.

1. I wanted to be able to reuse the focus square and animation, rather than only a single time.
2. I wanted the animation to disappear after it completed (something that I couldn't get @Anil's solution to do.
3. Instead of using `initWithFrame:`, I implemented my own `initWithTouchPoint:`.
4. I have a method for specifically animating the focus action.
5. I also have a method for updating the location of the frame.
6. The size of the frame is within `CameraFocusSquare`, which means that it's easier to find and update the size as needed.

**CameraFocusSquare.h**

```
@import UIKit;

@interface CameraFocusSquare : UIView

- (instancetype)initWithTouchPoint:(CGPoint)touchPoint;
- (void)updatePoint:(CGPoint)touchPoint;
- (void)animateFocusingAction;

@end
```

**CameraFocusSquare.m**

```
#import "CameraFocusSquare.h"

@implementation CameraFocusSquare {
    CABasicAnimation *_selectionBlink;
}

/**
 This is the init method for the square. It sets the frame for the view and sets border parameters. It also creates the blink animation.
 */
- (instancetype)initWithTouchPoint:(CGPoint)touchPoint {
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        [self updatePoint:touchPoint];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;

        // create the blink animation
        _selectionBlink = [CABasicAnimation
                animationWithKeyPath:@"borderColor"];
        _selectionBlink.toValue = (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        _selectionBlink.repeatCount = 3;  // number of blinks
        _selectionBlink.duration = 0.4;  // this is duration per blink
        _selectionBlink.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

/**
 Updates the location of the view based on the incoming touchPoint.
 */
- (void)updatePoint:(CGPoint)touchPoint {
    CGFloat squareWidth = 50;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - squareWidth/2, touchPoint.y - squareWidth/2, squareWidth, squareWidth);
    self.frame = frame;
}

/**
 This unhides the view and initiates the animation by adding it to the layer.
 */
- (void)animateFocusingAction {
    // make the view visible
    self.alpha = 1.0f;
    self.hidden = NO;
    // initiate the animation
    [self.layer addAnimation:_selectionBlink forKey:@"selectionAnimation"];
}

/**
 Hides the view after the animation stops. Since the animation is automatically removed, we don't need to do anything else here.
 */
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)flag {
    // hide the view
    self.alpha = 0.0f;
    self.hidden = YES;
}

@end
```

I initiate all of this on top of a view. This allows me greater flexibility and separates my UI code from my controller code (think MVC).

**PreviewView.h**

```
@import UIKit;

@interface PreviewView : UIView

- (IBAction)tapToFocus:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;

@end
```

**PreviewView.m**

```
#import "PreviewView.h"
#import "CameraFocusSquare.h"

@implementation PreviewView {
    CameraFocusSquare *_focusSquare;
}

- (IBAction)tapToFocus:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self];
    if (!_focusSquare) {
        _focusSquare = [[CameraFocusSquare alloc] initWithTouchPoint:touchPoint];
        [self addSubview:_focusSquare];
        [_focusSquare setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    else {
        [_focusSquare updatePoint:touchPoint];
    }
    [_focusSquare animateFocusingAction];
}

@end
```

Finally, in my `UIViewController` subclass, I have my `UITapGestureRecognizer` created and attached to the view. I also implement my tap-to-focus code here.

**CameraViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // do other initialization stuff here

    // create the tap-to-focus gesture
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapToFocusRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapToFocus:)];
    tapToFocusRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapToFocusRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.previewView addGestureRecognizer:tapToFocusRecognizer];
}

- (IBAction)tapToFocus:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer {
    if (!_captureDevice) {
        return;
    }
    if (![_captureDevice isFocusPointOfInterestSupported]) {
        return;
    }
    if (![_captureDevice isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus]) {
        return;
    }
    [self.previewView tapToFocus:tapGestureRecognizer];
    NSError *error;
    [_captureDevice lockForConfiguration:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error trying to lock configuration of camera. %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
    CGPoint touchPoint = [tapGestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.cameraView];
    // range of touch point is from (0,0) to (1,1)
    CGFloat touchX = touchPoint.x / self.previewView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat touchY = touchPoint.y / self.previewView.frame.size.height;

    _captureDevice.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus;
    if ([_captureDevice isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose]) {
        _captureDevice.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose;
    }
    _captureDevice.focusPointOfInterest = CGPointMake(touchX, touchY);
    if ([_captureDevice isExposurePointOfInterestSupported]) {
        _captureDevice.exposurePointOfInterest = CGPointMake(touchX, touchY);
    }
    [_captureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Hope this helps people so they can move onto more important code!

Comment: I havent tested it yet but by looking into it I can only say that its PERFECT!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic Swift view that will show an animated focus square. Just add it to your camera view and hook it up to the focus callback from a tap gesture recognizer.

```
@objc func didTapToFocus(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let pointInViewCoordinates = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)
    let pointInCameraCoordinates = cameraView.videoPreviewLayer.captureDevicePointConverted(fromLayerPoint: pointInViewCoordinates)
    camera.focusOn(pointInCameraCoordinates: pointInCameraCoordinates)
    cameraView.showFocusBox(at: pointInViewCoordinates)
}
```

Focus view:

```
final class CameraFocusBoxView: UIView {

    // MARK: - Instantiation

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        backgroundColor = .clear
        layer.addSublayer(focusBoxLayer)
    }

    // MARK: - API

    /// This zooms/fades in a focus square and blinks it a few times, then slowly fades it out
    func showBox(at point: CGPoint) {
        focusBoxLayer.removeAllAnimations()
        let scaleKey = "zoom in focus box"
        let fadeInKey = "fade in focus box"
        let pulseKey = "pulse focus box"
        let fadeOutKey = "fade out focus box"
        guard focusBoxLayer.animation(forKey: scaleKey) == nil,
              focusBoxLayer.animation(forKey: fadeInKey) == nil,
              focusBoxLayer.animation(forKey: pulseKey) == nil,
              focusBoxLayer.animation(forKey: fadeOutKey) == nil
            else { return }

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
        focusBoxLayer.position = point
        CATransaction.commit()

        let scale = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        scale.fromValue = 1
        scale.toValue = 0.375
        scale.duration = 0.3
        scale.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        scale.fillMode = .forwards

        let opacityFadeIn = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        opacityFadeIn.fromValue = 0
        opacityFadeIn.toValue = 1
        opacityFadeIn.duration = 0.3
        opacityFadeIn.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        opacityFadeIn.fillMode = .forwards

        let pulsing = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
        pulsing.toValue = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
        pulsing.repeatCount = 2
        pulsing.duration = 0.2
        pulsing.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.3 // wait for the fade in to occur

        let opacityFadeOut = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        opacityFadeOut.fromValue = 1
        opacityFadeOut.toValue = 0
        opacityFadeOut.duration = 0.5
        opacityFadeOut.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 2 // seconds
        opacityFadeOut.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        opacityFadeOut.fillMode = .forwards

        focusBoxLayer.add(scale, forKey: scaleKey)
        focusBoxLayer.add(opacityFadeIn, forKey: fadeInKey)
        focusBoxLayer.add(pulsing, forKey: pulseKey)
        focusBoxLayer.add(opacityFadeOut, forKey: fadeOutKey)
    }

    // MARK: - Private Properties

    private lazy var focusBoxLayer: CALayer = {
        let box = CALayer()
        box.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        box.borderWidth = 2
        box.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        box.opacity = 0
        return box
    }()

    // MARK: - Unsupported Initializers

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

}
```